# Adding a UINavigationController to a UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a set of 10 `navigationViewControllers` i want to the UITabBarController

this all just works fine except the fact when i want to see a UINavigationController that is in the "more" tab it doesn't switch to it. it does nothing. if i change that to a UIViewController it just works fine .. ok in the more tab you automatically have a UINavigationController to you disposal but if the user switches the tab's order and its not anymore in the "more" tab you don't have a `UINavigationController`...

any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Use UIViewControllers, and when you need additional navigation, push a UINavigationController on the stack, it'll solve your problem for any use case.

Not sure you're design really needs 10 UINavigationController. Much better to change titles and buttons while navigating. But i'm not sure what you're trying to do.